# How to count all records and outputs when a condition is met? [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to count all clients and output the signup date for the 4th customer who has signed up.
I mean, evaluate the number of clients that signed up and once the count of clients that have signed up reaches 4 to output the signup date and the id of the 4th customer

Sample table

```
customer_id     signup_date   
3994            2020-01-01
9393            2020-01-02
2144            2020-01-03
8373            2020-01-04
```

Output table

```
customer_id   signup_date
8373            2020-01-04
```

Comment: read up on ORDER BY and LIMIT

Comment: Does that applied on the first four customers only or for every four customers signed up? i.e. customer 4, customer 8 , customer 12, ...

Comment: `select * from (select *, row_number() over(order by signup_date) as rn from t) x where rn = 4`

Comment: Thanks, Impaler, you may post it as an answer

Comment: What should happen on #5?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to identify the location of each row according to a specific ordering.

In the query shown below the subquery computes the column `rn` by using the  `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Then the outer query can just filter out the rows according to the value of this column:

```
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over(order by signup_date) as rn 
  from t
) x 
where rn = 4
```

Comment: Good answer! Just worth mentioning `ROW_NUMBER` will only work in MySQL 8.0.0 or higher - but there are [other slightly hacky solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) for previous versions.

Comment: @SteveChambers I have mixed opinions about that (depending on the day, I guess). On one side, MySQL 5.x is reaching end of life in 14 months from now, but on the flip side tons of people are still using it. Maybe Oracle will extends its life at some point.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM t
    ORDER BY signup_date
    LIMIT 1  OFFSET 3
```

(Works on all versions of MySQL.)